# Python, text coming out weird when reading + writing file simultaneously

Tags: python

The results comes out really weird when I try to read and write a .txt file simultaneously in Python.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print """The contents of this .txt file will now be erased.
if you don don't wish to do this. Hit CTRL+C.
if you want to do this. Just click ENTER.
"""
raw_input("> ")

target = open(filename, 'w+') #opens the file to read+write simultaneously

newline1 = raw_input("the first line: ") #three lines of strings to add to the .txt file
newline2 = raw_input("the second line: ") 
newline3 = raw_input("the third line: ")


target.write(("%s\n%s\n%s") % (newline1, newline2, newline3)) #writes the lines to the file

print "this is what's currently written inside the .txt file:\n"
print target.read() #reads the contents of the file 
target.close() #closes and saves the file
```

But then the contents of the file just reads out this jibberish (both inside the .txt files, and when it's read in the program), instead of 3 simple lines:

```
 s·   d  Z  d d l Z d e j f d „  ƒ  YZ d e j f d „  ƒ  YZ d e j f d „  ƒ  YZ d   e e j f d
 „  ƒ  YZ d e e j f d „  ƒ  YZ d
 „  Z d Z e j    e ƒ Z
 d S(   sv    Python Character Mapping Codec cp1252 generated from 'MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT' with gencodec.py.

iÿÿÿÿNt   Codecc           B   s    e  Z d  d „ Z d  d „ Z RS(   t   strictc         C   s   t  j | | t ƒ S(   N(   t   codecst   charmap_encodet   encoding_table(   t   selft   inputt   errors(    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyt   encode   s    c         C   s   t  j | | t ƒ S(   N(   R   t   charmap_decodet   decoding_table(   R   R   R   (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyt   decode   s    (   t   __name__t
   __module__R   R   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR          s   t   IncrementalEncoderc           B   s   e  Z e d  „ Z RS(   c         C   s   t  j | |  j t ƒ d S(   Ni    (   R   R   R   R   (   R   R   t   final(    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR      s    (   R   R
   t   FalseR   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR      s   t   IncrementalDecoderc           B   s   e  Z e d  „ Z RS(   c         C   s   t  j | |  j t ƒ d S(   Ni    (   R   R       R   R
   (   R   R   R   (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR      s    (   R   R
   R   R   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR      s   t   StreamWriterc           B   s   e  Z RS(    (   R   R
   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR      s   t   StreamReaderc           B   s   e  Z RS(    (   R   R
   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyR      s   c           C   s@   t  j d d d t ƒ  j d t ƒ  j d t d t d t d t ƒ S(      Nt   namet   cp1252R   R   t   incrementalencodert   incrementaldecodert   streamreadert   streamwriter(    R   t       CodecInfoR    R   R   R   R   R   R   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyt   getregentry!   s        u–      

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~â‚¬ï¿¾â€šÆ’â€žâ€¦â€ â€¡Ë†â€°Å â€¹Å’ï¿¾Å½ï¿¾ï¿¾â€˜â€™â€œâ€â€¢â€“â€”Ëœâ„¢Å¡â€ºÅ“ï¿¾Å¾Å¸Â Â¡Â¢Â£Â¤Â¥Â¦Â§Â¨Â©ÂªÂ«Â¬Â­Â®Â¯Â°Â±Â²Â³Â´ÂµÂ¶Â·Â¸Â¹ÂºÂ»Â¼Â½Â¾Â¿Ã€ÃÃ‚ÃƒÃ„Ã…Ã†Ã‡ÃˆÃ‰ÃŠÃ‹ÃŒÃÃŽÃÃÃ‘Ã’Ã“Ã”Ã•Ã–Ã—Ã˜Ã™ÃšÃ›ÃœÃÃžÃŸÃ Ã¡Ã¢Ã£Ã¤Ã¥Ã¦Ã§Ã¨Ã©ÃªÃ«Ã¬Ã­Ã®Ã¯Ã°Ã±Ã²Ã³Ã´ÃµÃ¶Ã·Ã¸Ã¹ÃºÃ»Ã¼Ã½Ã¾Ã¿(   t   __doc__R   R    R   R   R   R   R   R
   t
   charmap_buildR   (    (    (    s#   C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyt   <module>   s     ÿ            ó:›› ™øÌ pò  åP§ü                        a^v– Qý LýHVzàý0DýI.*Èý ýJ²ã¨@ÏüðÒüK6=XÙü0Ùü                        NÆü­ü ËüOžç5˜¯üp¯üÂ±v%P¿õýüQöy€Íüà­ü•ëw@MýMýSž@3 èü˜õü_å’Ï`FýøDý            ßEïÐþü­ü¹ý¥t€ìüXþüXžf9`âü0Ùü            Z2ðÀãüˆÛü            O°s÷ÀýhØü]B] ìüþü^ÒÏZ€ýðý_NÅô Èü §ü            GbP€åüÐÞüDÆíÂ OüXþüc20F@HýxGýH¯«ÐPBý ¬üeú¿ýüðüüf¾Àëü(üüeõ5¸óüóü            ¼å»úXDý0Dý            k®à áüÔülš¦ âü0¤ü            n"éÍ@!ý8Aý½-ò¡àý¸ý            q.&yxLýPLý            s¦v8(×ü0Ôü            ¾]ª[àÝü¸Ýü;
RE`ý ¬ü                                                            |I\ ýÐ   ýBÃœ”`ýÀý            0õ Èü°¦ü            fPãÑü@Íü‚ª¥¨¾õpðüƒª¥à¼õ0¤üMÕ—pJýHJý…JÃ1 ÍüpÐü            ‡ÊÑÈ@îüè ýˆd, Ïü`Ñü                        ‹úDâ ý€ýŒêGœ€ýÀ@ýjhü ×üÔü½L ÀHýhHý            Æ Q`öü8öü\¤è½õ`Ñüõ\} ý°Aý                        n¸ì™Àý° ý                        ˜ª¥ð¾õÀúü™ª¥Ø¾õ¨ùüŽÞõ`ý¨Iý›¦[ ý€DýœÂ© Nü¸Ýü†T !ýÈBýžª¥À¾õñü             V$¶àìüøþü¡„½@ïüðý            £ŒMÀæüˆñü¤2/,ØühØüÆK¬§ ý€ý¦†? ýðý            ¨Šrxý° ý©†L
`Ûü8Ûü            «þa
```

Edit: it worked after I added the `target.seek(0)` line before reading. But would still be interesting to know what causes the jibberish to be written!

Comment: try target.seek(0) before reading?

Comment: You cannot write, then read, without rewinding the file position header. Use `file.seek()` to do so (`file.seek(0)` goes back to the start).

Comment: Adding `target.seek(0)` before `print target.read()` gives me the expected output.  Even without the `seek` call I can still see the correct output in the text file, I'm not sure how you are getting so much gibberish in your file.

Comment: I think trying to read past the file is what gives gibberish.

Comment: I just get no output with python 2.7.6.

Comment: When I added the target.seek(0) line before reading I got the expected results.

But would still be intresting to know why the contents came out so wierd without it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to `file.flush()` before seeking.

Otherwise, keep two handles to the file:

```
file = open(filename, "w")
file.write(stuff)
file.close()

file = open(filename, "r")
file.read()
```

I wouldn't consider it good practice to write and turn around to read the file again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. When I asked my teacher he said this is happening because I tried to read the file after writing it and, because of writing file pointer moves to the end of the file but as per our expectation we want to read the file from beginning so for that we need to use `file_object.seek(0)` which set the pointer to the 0th position and it worked!

```
f=open('new.txt','w+') 
f.write("i am new to python")
f.seek(0)
data=f.read() 
print (data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? Some of the material I removed made it look like a question, but the remaining material looks like an answer to me.